# Binding vs MultiBinding => Different results

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a `TextBlock` inside a `StackPanel`. Since I'm using `TextTrimming`, I have to set manully the `TextBox`'s width according the `StackPanel.ActualWidth`.

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock.Width>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WidthConverter}">
                <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}" Path="TemplatedParent.Parent.ActualWidth"  />
              </MultiBinding.Bindings>
             </MultiBinding>                
        </TextBlock.Width>
    </TextBlock>
```

My converter:

```vb
Public Class WidthConverter
    Implements IMultiValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(ByVal values() As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.Convert

        Const TextBoxMarginRight As Double = 5

        Dim ParentWidth As Double = CType(CType(values(0), FrameworkElement).Parent, FrameworkElement).ActualWidth

        Dim ParentRelativeControlPosition As Point = CType(values(0), FrameworkElement).TransformToAncestor(CType(CType(values(0), FrameworkElement).Parent, Media.Visual)).Transform(New Point(0, 0))

        Dim Width As Double = ParentWidth - TextBoxMarginRight - ParentRelativeControlPosition.X

        If Width > 5 Then
            Return Width
        Else
            Return 0
        End If

    End Function
```

Why is this working correctly and not that code below ? (using a `IValueConverter` with same code):

My converter can get the `StackPanel` but `ActualWidth` is always zero

```
<TextBlock.Width>

    <Binding RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}" Path="TemplatedParent.Parent.ActualWidth"  Converter="{StaticResource WidthConverter}" />          
</TextBlock.Width>
```

Comment: I think that MultiBinding is made AFTER TextBlock rendering, and (single)Binding BEFORE TextBlok rendering

Comment: Hello, I may have had the same problem, with a binding to an image source. I posted a topic about it and a small project to test:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128307/special-behavior-of-multibinding-vs-binding-when-specifying-an-imagesource

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel}}"
```