# Special behavior of MultiBinding vs Binding when specifying an ImageSource

Tags: wpf, binding, multibinding, imagesource

I ran into a special behavior when binding to the `Source` property of an `Image`, using a converter.

It appears that if I use a simple `Binding` with a `IValueConverter` that returns a string correpsonding to a relative path to the image, everything is OK and the image is displayed.

On the other hand, if I use a `MultiBinding` with a `IMultiValueConverter` that returns the same string, the binding doesn't work and this error message is displayed in VS2010 output window :

> System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='' MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')

I found out that for this to work, I can't return a simple string (and not even a `Uri`). I instead have to create a ImageSource in my converter (a `BitmapImage`, in fact) and return it.

Do you know why this strange behavior happens? Is this a known difference between `Binding` and `MultiBinding`, or is it a bug?

I found [another stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909511/binding-vs-multibinding-different-results) that may relate to this, where Alvin posted a comment about the time when the binding are resolved :

> I think that MultiBinding is made AFTER TextBlock rendering, and (single)Binding BEFORE TextBlok rendering – Avlin

To Illustrate this problem, I wrote a small project that you can [download and test](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/61987557/MultiBindingOnImageSource.zip).

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that this is by design but to be sure you would need to ask one of the developers, the difference is just that no [type conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645047.aspx) is applied to the values returned  by `MultiBindings`, people trip on that fairly often.

Comment: Interesting. It is maybe because the developers thought that as long as you have to use a converter with a multibinding, you could (should) return the right type of data anyway. I haven't thought about this before. Thanks!

Comment: @AntoineJeanrichard: You don't necessarily have to use a converter by the way, you can also use the [`StringFormat` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) to construct a string with the bindings as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working as followed (simplified code !)

My XAML:

```html
<MediaElement LoadedBehavior="Play" Stretch="UniformToFill">
    <MediaElement.Source>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ActionMedia_Converter}"> 
            <Binding Path="HomeW_Background_FileName" />
            <Binding Path="HomeW_Background_FileType" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </MediaElement.Source>
</MediaElement>
```

My converter :

```html
Public Class ActionMedia_Converter
 Implements IMultiValueConverter

 Public Function Convert(values As Object(), TargetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IMultiValueConverter.Convert
  Dim ImageSource As String

  ImageSource = String.Concat(values(0), ".", values(1))

  Dim MyUri = New System.Uri(ImageSource)
  
  Return MyUri

 End Function

 Public Function ConvertBack(values As Object, targetTypes As Type(), parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object() Implements IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack
  Return Binding.DoNothing
 End Function

End Class
```